# Javascript broken in IE11 and old browsers - node+react+webpack production build

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, reactjs, webpack

On just about every browser, Javascript appears to be working fine. However, with some older browsers and IE11, it appears broken.

I suspect this is the case because when submitting a form `event.preventDefault()` isn't firing. And another function isn't being called. However React router seems to work correctly. I'm also using jQuery (yes I know) which doesn't seem to work either when I try to run console commands.

Here is my Webpack config:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

var config = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './app/main'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'js'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
    })
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          plugins: [
            ['react-transform', {
              transforms: [
                {
                  transform: 'react-transform-hmr',
                  imports: ['react'],
                  locals: ['module']
                }, {
                  transform: 'react-transform-catch-errors',
                  imports: ['react', 'redbox-react']
                }
              ]
            }]
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  config.plugins.push(
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compressor: {
        screw_ie8: true,
        warnings: false
      }
    })
  );
}

module.exports = config;
```

What I'm importing in my main file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import { betaRequest } from '../actions/auth'
import Messages from './Messages'
import $ from 'jquery'
```

I'm also (unfortunately) using Jade for the "root" file:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    meta(http-equiv='x-ua-compatible', content='ie=edge')
    meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
    title='...'
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/main.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee+Shade')
  body
    #app!= html
    script.
    window.INITIAL_STATE = !{JSON.stringify(initialState)}

    script(src='/js/lib/jquery.js')
    script(src='/js/lib/bootstrap.js')
    script(src='/js/bundle.js')

    // Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID.
    script.
      (function(b,o,i,l,e,r){b.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l;b[l]||(b[l]=
      function(){(b[l].q=b[l].q||[]).push(arguments)});b[l].l=+new Date;
      e=o.createElement(i);r=o.getElementsByTagName(i)[0];
      e.src='https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js';
      r.parentNode.insertBefore(e,r)}(window,document,'script','ga'));
      ga('create','...','auto');ga('send','pageview');
```

Function for submitting form:

```
  handleSignup(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.dispatch(submit(this.state.name, this.state.email));

  }
```

Also not working in production:

```
  jumpToPlaceOnPage() {
    $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: document.getElementById("requestBetaSection").offsetTop
        }, 800);
  }
```

Getting the following error:
`(index):1 EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/html") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection.`

Comment: If there aren't any errors, then how exactly is it not working?

Comment: See question above @RobM.

Comment: It doesn't sound like the error is coming from any of the code you posted, can you post the form where `event.preventDefault()` isn't working and also the other function that isn't working? Also, `event.preventDefault()` isn't supported in older versions of IE (IE11 should be fine though) - not sure what "old browsers" encompasses

Comment: Added form submission code and only other code that also it's executing @RobM.

Comment: And there now is an error @RobM.

Comment: Have you searched that error? https://github.com/glenjamin/webpack-hot-middleware/issues/26